Graphic device remains in invalid state after resizing window when using layout() with lcm()
I have a function that generates a plot matrix using layout() withlcm() defining the lengths and widths. When resizing the plot window down to a size too small to accommodate  the previously defined length and width parameters, the plot window generates a "Figure region too large" as would be expected.
I would  expect the function, when rerun, to generate a properly sized plot for the resized plot window given that the dev.size("cm") function correctly recognizes the resized plot window dimension. But instead, it keeps throwing an invalid graphics state error message.
Here's a scaled down version of my custom plot routine:
.pardef <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)

# Set grid layout
lmin <- min(dev.size("cm")) # Get smallest window side in cm
dim.cm <- lmin / 3
layout(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3), 
       widths  = rep(lcm(dim.cm), 9), 
       heights = rep(lcm(dim.cm), 9))


# Generate plots
# Set the margins to zero
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0), pty = "s")
on.exit(par(.pardef))

# Create the plots within the grid layout
for (i in 1:9) {
  plot(1:10, main = paste("Plot", i))
}
par(.pardef)


One workaround is to clear the device (which I would rather not do if I want to toggle back to previous plots). The other is to send a generic plot (like  plot(0, type='n',axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)) to clear the error state at which point my custom function can regenerate the plot matrix for the resized window.  However, if I am to follow up with simple plot (instead of recreating my plot matrix), I need to reset the layout using par(mfrow=c(1,1)).
Some of these workarounds can be implemented with a tryCatch() function, but this is far from ideal. I'm seeking a tidier and more robust solution to this problem.

Side note. If looping over plot() use lapply instead of for: lapply(seq(9), \(i) plot(seq(10), main = paste("Plot", i))).
